# How to set up dependencies that should be enabled only in test or dev mode in play framework?

Tags: playframework

Currently the play framework [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/dependency) says how to setup dependencies for the whole project without dividing them between running modes. The previous method allowed this by putting something like `%test.` before module definitions in the `application.conf` file (which still works).

Is there a way to do it right in the `dependencies.yml` file, or should it be still mixed with the old method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think it's possible to differentiate dependencies between dev/prod/test mode.
The %test was designed only to set some configurations, not change the deps IMO.
But, modifying the DependencyManager play class to manage a different dependencies.yml according to the running mode shouldn't be difficult.
We could almost ask directly to play list if people would like to have it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/guide10#aMeasuringcodecoveragea) is an example of using the `%test.` prefix for specifying modules according to the running mode.

Comment: This is not really a dependency with the Ivy meaning, this is just a configuration taken into account by application.conf. Anyway, I don't think this can be managed by dependencies.yml because I don't any code doing that... Once again, I may be wrong!